# Codeigniter -> Undefined Variable

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, variables, view

I am unsure as too why I am getting the following errors when trying to pass data through to my html email template -> The PHP errors are coming from the view.

```
Undefined variable: companyName -> line 9

Undefined variable: firstName -> line 12
```

**Controller:**

```
function _userRegEmail($activateCode,$email,$firstname,$lastname){
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['companyEmail'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactEmail;
        $data['companyContact'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactName;
        $data['firstName'] = $firstname;
        $data['lastName'] = $lastname;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['activateCode'] = $activateCode;

        $this->email->from($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactEmail, $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName);
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName 'User Registration Confirmation');

        $messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg','', TRUE);

        $this->email->message($messageContent);

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

**View:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 600px;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;font-family: Arial, &quot;MS Trebuchet&quot;, sans-serif">
        <div class="header" style="width: 100%">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;color: #00afd8"><?php echo $companyName; ?></h1>
            </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 15px">Hello <?php echo $firstName; ?></h2>
                <p style="margin-left: 15px">Thank you for signing up to Farm Ads.</p>
                <p style="margin-left: 15px">Could you please click <a href="<?php base_url(); ?>users/confirm/"<?php $activateCode; ?>>here</a> to activate your account.</p>

                <div class="from">
                    <p class="bold" style="margin-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px">Regards,</p>
                    <p style="margin-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px"><?php $companyContact; ?></p>
                    </div>
             </div> 
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the variables you have set in $data in the view you shouldn't do:

```
$messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg','', TRUE);
```

But:

```
$messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg', $data, TRUE);
```

This makes sure you send the variables to the view so they can be used in there like you are trying already.